# Install Openstack

Tags: landscape, openstack-autopilot

i would like to know if Ubuntu Openstack can be installed on Digital Ocean Servers? Does it needs to install MASS even if im using Digital Ocean Servers?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Of course, usually anything can be done, but you will be fighting uphill to do it.  [Ubuntu OpenStack](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/ubuntu-openstack) is designed to be installed in a datacenter on top of [MAAS](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/tools/maas).